# how to encrypt the chat message with multiple people public key together and restore the message?

Tags: cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I have a application with two users and one middle man, all of them holding the private and public key, To make the secured chat, two users and one middle man are all sending the public key and generate a secured channel. After establishing the channel, the middle man doesn't have the ability to see the encrypted message unless one of the user is sending his own key to the middle man.

i am not very familiar with cryptography, so for this app i know how to encrypt and decrypt the message.

```
encrypt(data) {
    try {
        var cipher = Crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', this.password);
        var encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data), "utf8")), cipher.final()]);
        FileSystem.writeFileSync(this.filePath, encrypted);
        return { message: "Encrypted!" };
    } catch (exception) {
        throw new Error(exception.message);
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to establish the encrypted channel from the stakeholders' key, and how can the one middle to see the message using his key and one of users' key?

is there a way to accomplish this using the cryptography?

Comment: This is usually done with a common session key which is itself individiually encrypted for each owner of a private-public key pair. This is the scheme that PGP uses - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy

Comment: I only see mention of a symmetric cipher in your code (AES), what public key crypto are you planning to use?

Comment: it should not be public key crypto, my fault.  My purpose is to let the middleman (which is the server that all the chat messages go through ) can't see the encrypted message unless one user send his key with middleman 's key. My question is how would the middleman plays in with PGP, if middleman and two users use their keys together for the encryption, they will all have exchanged the keys,  how can allow both user see the encrypted message while the middleman don't see until he has one of users key.

Comment: E2e chat encryption is a very hard problem to do correctly, there are only a couple of solutions that seem to be secure and these were developed by well versed crypto designers. The probability of creating a secure multi person chat app are very close to zero, best to not even try if you care about the user's security.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand, but I think if you want to go with a system that doesn't use public key crypto I would suggest a system using 2 stages of encryption, actually a lot like PGP only both stages use symmetric keys-

1) There is a fixed session key generated by the first person in the chat, this can be a randomly generated number.

2) This session key is then encrypted by the keys belonging to every new member of the chat group and individually sent to them.

3) The new members decrypt with their own unique keys to get the plaintext session key back.

4) This session key is subsequently used to decrypt the messages sent to all participants. The same key can also be used to encrypt and send any new messages from any entitled participant(i.e. has the valid session key) on the chat group.

This is used in some systems but it relies on the unique keys being securely transmitted, in the first instance. If this condition can't be met, it's a problem that can be solved with public key crypto to build an end-to-end secure message system like PGP, whatsapp, etc.

Comment: I guess "session key is then encrypted by the keys belonging to every new member" will be encrypted with the asymmetric public key of each recipient?

Comment: Hey Zaph, that would be the case in a public key system. As far as I can tell the OP doesn't want to do this. Presumably they want AES to secure everything so all keys are symmetric. This is actually a viable system if you can have pre-shared keys.

Comment: "if you can have pre-shared keys" but that is the main problem.